# Difference Between Double Implications and Equal Signs

Tags: logic, notation

I always thought equal signs (=), indicated double implications, however after thinking about this example, I am very confused.

For example, the Theorem (in Linear Algebra):

L($\vec{0}$) = $\vec{0}$, where L is a linear mapping can be described as:

In the equation L($\vec{x}$) = $\vec{y}$, 
if $\vec{x}$ = $\vec{0}$, then $\vec{y}$ = $\vec{0}$.

However, the other implication is not true, which is
if $\vec{y}$ = $\vec{0}$, then $\vec{x}$ = $\vec{0}$.

Do equals not always indicate double implications?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In logic, the equal sign expresses [equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) between *terms*, i.e. "names" for objects, like e.g. 
 $2=1+1$.

[Bi-conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional#Definition) (i.e. *double implication*) is a *connective* "connecting" formulas, like e.g. $p \leftrightarrow q$.

---

Regarding the "equation" : $L(0)=0$, maybe it is only the expression of a *function* $L$ that for input (argument) $0$ returns output (value) $0$.

In this case, it is an equality as expressed above : we have a "name" for an object (a number), i.e. the value of the function $L$ for argument $0$, and the exprssion asserts that that value is (equal to the number) $0$.

Comment: So you're telling me equal signs do not always stand for double implications? So an equal sign can mean no implication, a single implication or double implication?

Comment: Or I guess a better way to explain that is to state that equals signs and the type of implication are unrelated. Moreover, an equal sign can stand for no implication, a single implication or double implication. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: @TimWeah - another symbols used for *double implication* is $\equiv$. It has three "segments" in order to be different from the $=$ (that is ubiquitous in math).

Answer (score 1):

> "$L(x)=y$" means:

**Term** $L(x)$ equals **term** $y$.

---

> "If $A$ then $B$" means:

**Proposition** $A$ implies **proposition**  $B$ or

Whenever **proposition** $A$ is true then **Proposition** $B$ must also be true

---

For the latter it does not matter, if $A$ or $B$ include some terms containing equality signs or not.

Comment: So youre saying L($\vec{0}$) = $\vec{0}$ is really an implication not an equation?

Comment: @TimWeah not quite. $L(x)$ and $y$ are terms (so not true or false). $L(x)=y$ is an equation or atomic proposition (can be true or false). It is not an implication. "If $L(x)=y$ and $x=0$ then $y=0$" is again a proposition / an implication (it is false if $L(x)=y$ and $x=0$ is true and $y=0$ is false, it is true otherwise).

Comment: So (true) equations do not always translate to double implications? They can be no, one-way, or double implications?

Comment: Equations have nothing to do with implications. However an equation can be part of an implication (if A then B) or of a double implication (if A then B and if B then A). By *can be part* I mean that an equation might be the A or B in such a (double-)implication.

Comment: Ok thanks. So I guess I shouldn't have compared them in the first place. I just had this weird notion that equal means double implications. So it is safe to conclude that (other than how an equation may be A or B in a (double) implication), they are not connected to each other at all (especially logic wise)? Sorry for asking so many questions.

Comment: Correct - an equation *can not be* an implication or double implication (saying it could would be a misconcept). An equation *can just be a part* of an implication or double implication.

Comment: Thank you so much! I believe you 100%, but for some reason, I feel like single and double implications are connected with equations (equal signs) (in a way other than what you mentioned). I honestly don't know why.

Comment: An equation is what you call an **atomic proposition** (includes only an equation symbol and no logical signs like implication, and, or, not). Therefore such an atomic formula will never be an implication. An implication is a proposition that includes a logical implication Symbol (if ... then...).

Comment: But couldn't you argue that the "logic" is similar. Like for the implications "If A then B", and "If B then A", (so A iff B), contains the same logic as A=B. No? Because since A IFF B is either true or false, isnt it also an atomic proposition?

Comment: $A\leftrightarrow B$ means A is true iff B is true (A and B are **propositions** that can be true or false). $L(x)=y$ means that $L(x)$ euqals $y$. Here neither $L(x)$ not $y$ can be true or false, but they are just elementary language expressions you call **terms**.With such Terms you can build up **atomic propositions** (using equation signs) and with the atomic popositions in turn you can build more complex **propositions** using logical signs (like iumplication).

Comment: $1$ and $2$ are **Terms**. $1=2$ is an **atomic proposition**. $1=2\rightarrow L(x)=17$ is a **proposition** (in this case an implication).

Comment: Oh I see, so equations are like a "logical step below" propositions. So if t1 and t2 are terms, then t1 = t2 would be an atomic proposition (equation). If we have A = (t1 = t2) and B = (t3 = t4), then A and B would be atomic propositions (equations) and the statements: "If A then B", or "If B then A", or "A IFF B", would be complex propositions (single/double implications).

Comment: So you're initial explanation of "equations vs (single and double) implications" was correct where they are not related to each other at all, except for how equations (atomic propositions) make up (single and double) implications (complex propositions)

Comment: ....yep! great!

Comment: Language is built up in steps: (1) Terms (variables, constants, function symbols), (2) atomic propositions (terms with equality or relations like < etc.), (3) propositions (atomic propositions with logical symbols like and or not implication etc.).

Comment: but back to my original question, I understand that the equation L(0) = 0 is either true or false, but the terms L(0) and 0 cannot be true or false. But is it incorrect to view the equation L(0)=0 the way I described it? (Which is in the equation L(x) = y, if x = 0 then y = 0)

Comment: @TimWeah That is correct. And you *can* reverse it: you just get "If y=0 then L(x)=0". But that doesn't necessarily tell you that x is zero! The nonreversible thing is the *function*, not the equality.

Comment: Say $L:V\rightarrow W$ is a linear mapping with $V$ and $W$ being some $k$-vector spaces. It is correct that (1) $L(0)=0$, (2) in general there might be $x\neq 0$ with $L(x)=0$. If u like ..in another way (1) if $x=0$ then $L(x)=0$, (2) if $L(x)=0$ then $x=0$ ..is not in general true.